# Xamarin.Forms Grid with Images - Spacing doesn't work

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to implement a grid with images. In this case images are numbers and it looks like a Phone Dialer:

[image: Phone Dialer]

I want to achieve this (please do not pay attention to a red box..):
[image: desired layout]

XAML Code looks like:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout x:Name="MainStackLayout"
                     Spacing="15"
                     Padding="{Binding MainStackSidePadding}">
            <Grid x:Name="pinGrid" 
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                  ColumnSpacing="2" 
                  RowSpacing="3">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image x:Name="pinPad1" Source="pinPad01.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPad2" Source="pinPad02.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPad3" Source="pinPad03.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="AspectFit"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPad4" Source="pinPad04.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPad5" Source="pinPad05.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPad6" Source="pinPad06.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="AspectFit"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPad7" Source="pinPad07.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPad8" Source="pinPad08.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPad9" Source="pinPad09.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPad0" Source="pinPad00.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>

                <Image x:Name="pinPadBcksp" Source="pinPadbackspace.png" HeightRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonRadious}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

It looks like `RowSpacing` and `ColumnSpacing` properties doesn't be implemented?
I want to put some more spacing between rows (identically as spacing between columns)

Comment: Row and Column spacing should do the work, but if they don't you can always add extra column and rows as spacing (just need to set right height and width)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza this image is a acual output. Please see my updated question with image what I want. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like RowSpacing and ColumnSpacing properties don't be implemented

Actually, it is implemented. I bet what's going on here is a misunderstanding of this concepts. I've taken your code (with some simplification) and printed out the screen it provides. It seemed pretty similar to what you want to achieve.

My simplified code is this:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MainStackLayout"
             Spacing="15">
    <Grid x:Name="pinGrid" 
          HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
          Margin="30,0"
          ColumnSpacing="20" 
          RowSpacing="20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
        <Image Source="Icon" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

To show exactly what I mean, I changed the back color and highlight the layout bounds.

And here is the output. On the left, `ColumnSpacing=2` and `RowSpacing=3`, right: `ColumnSpacing=20` and `Grid`'s `Margin="30,0"`:

[image: Tiny spacing columns][image: huge spacing columns]

Notice that the images I'm using almost haven't changed their dispositions. It' because of the `Aspect="AspectFit"` property, that make the image take the maximum size keeping its aspect, what doesn't occurs when you change it to `Fill`.

Unless it changes effectively the amount of space that will be used for the image it will not make big visual alterations, but it's working.

Using an `Android` device or emulator, you can switch on `Show Layout Bounds` on `Developer Settings`. It I'll make your job much easier when designing this kind of views.

**Summarily:** The spacing is working. It is set in dpi, so it can looks diffenrently on each device and the image itself will not suffer big changes using `AspectFit`.

Comment: Thanks man! AspectFit did the job, and thanks for better understanding :)